# Is there a way to compare a value against multiple possibilities without repetitive if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a function with an input that can be of multiple possibilities, and each one triggers a different function.

The example code here works, but it's very bad and I don't want to use this sort of code:

```
def start(press_type):
    if press_type == "keyboard":
        function1()

    if press_type == "left click":
        function2()

    if press_type == "right click":
        function3()

    if press_type == "middle click":
        function4()
```

Is there any way to write the function without repeating those `if`/`else` statements?

I tried to use a dictionary, but the result was difficult to work with, also, I have a couple other parameters with multiple set options, so this method would end up being convoluted eventually.

Comment: If any attempt to improve the code made it more difficult to work with, then keep this code. It's good as-is. The usual suggestion would be to use a dictionary to map the different "press type" values to the functions, but you seem to already know that.

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, but from the looks of it, you want the if statements after the first to be `elif` statements.  On the other hand, this looks like a dictionary approach should have been easy to work with, unless further if statements are more complex than what you've shown here.

Comment: See [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASRqxDGutpA) which discusses match, dictionary and if-else. Conclusion: if-else is usually the most efficient and clearest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pattern match statement:

```py
def start(press_type):
    match press_type:
        case "keyboard":
            function1()
        case "left clock":
            function2()
        # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3.10+

```py
def start(press_type):
  match press_type:
    case 'keyboard':
      function1()
    case 'left click':
        function2()
    case 'right click':
        function3()
    case 'middle click':
        function4()
    case _:
      # Default
    # ...and so on.
```

Reference: [Structural Pattern Matching](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this answer will be unpopular but the `match/case` solutions, so far offered, simply make use of a new feature in python 3.10, which to a large degree doesn't really simplify the multiple options that you imply, may be used in the future.

There is a case for using a traditional dictionary approach and then adding a keywords option to the functions.

I don't see this approach being any less convoluted than the `match/case` approach. ( I may be wrong! )

A simple example:

```
def start(press_type, **kwargs):
    func = functions[press_type]
    func(**kwargs)

def function1(**kwargs):
    print("function 1 executed")

def function2(**kwargs):
    print("function 2 executed")
    if kwargs:
        if "key1" in kwargs:
            function21(kwargs["key1"])
        if "key2" in kwargs:
            function21(kwargs["key2"])
        if "key3" in kwargs:
            function23(kwargs["key3"])
        return
    print("    function 2 missing a parameter")

def function3(**kwargs):
    print("function 3 executed")

def function4(**kwargs):
    print("function 4 executed")

def function21(key=None):
    print("    function 21", key)

def function23(key=None):
    print("    function 23", key)


functions = {"keyboard":function1,"left click":function2,"right click":function3,"middle click":function4}


start("left click", key1=1, key2=2, key3=3)
start("keyboard")
start("left click", key1=42, key3="A")
start("right click")
start("left click")
```

Output:

```
function 2 executed
    function 21 1
    function 21 2
    function 23 3
function 1 executed
function 2 executed
    function 21 42
    function 23 A
function 3 executed
function 2 executed
    function 2 missing a parameter
```

Comment: Python match-case was never intended as a simple switch statement (as used in C etc). It does much more and so there is a lot more code behind the scenes so it is not efficient for simple switch-like uses. Although the dictionary approach can look neat it can also be less clear than if-else and is not more efficient.

Comment: @user19077881 Basically, I agree with you. I first came across it in the Algol language (I think), many years ago but this new python use is much more sophisticated.